# UIButton not working on ipad when i add a specific constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

When i add my button constraint of *Vertical Spacing* with another UILabel object, it does not work on ipad. Please have a look at attached image:

[image: View]

When i add *SIGN UP* button(highlighted with blue color) a vertical spacing constraint with *DON'T YOU HAVE AN ACCOUNT* label it starts to not working on *ipad*(iphone is still ok).

If i delete button, add a new one, etc. the same thing happens. A notable issue is other button(written *SIGN IN* and have green background) does not have any such problem. All subviews are in the same hierarchy. Is there anybody that know why it is happening?

Comment: Probably the UILabel goes over UIButton; do you try to add a vertical space between UILabel and SIGNUP UIButton?

Comment: That's the case when i add that it does not working.

Comment: Also, I've thought about these kind of size/covering stuffs, when i increased height of the button or vertical space constant problem still appears.

Comment: Could you display the constraint rules for each element in UIView?

Comment: What do you mean by it stops working? Have you checked your size classes?

Comment: I've not said it stops. I've said when i add the constraint it starts not working on iPad, which means the button does work on iPhone but does not on iPad. No, i've not checked the size classes property, is it supposed to be enabled or disabled?

Comment: @DilaraAlbayrak I am having same problem. have you solve this issue. if you get any solution about it. please give me some suggestion.